# Best practice for specifiying component interface in react.js?

Tags: reactjs, interface, components, state

I wrote a component `Foo` in React.js (its parameter "interface" consists of a single parameter `text`; there are more parameters in my real code):

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Foo extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }

  render(){
    return <div>{this.props.text}</div>;
  }
}
```

and I thought I could improve the code by **modifying the property access** as:

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Foo extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this._text = props.text
  }

  render(){
    return <div>{this._text}</div>;
  }
}
```

This would give me the benefits that

- I can immediately see **what properties are supported** by having a look at the constructor.
- The code that applies the properties gets shorter/**better to read**.

However, this **destroys the update workflow** for the property. In a **parent component** I use `Foo` like

```
<Foo text={this.state.parentText}/>
```

and

```
this.setState({parentText: "new text"})
```

does not trigger an update of the text in `Foo` any more. The constructor of `Foo` is only called once and therefore, the private variable `this._text` is not updated on property changes.

=> Using extra private properties to modify the parameter access turned out to be a bad idea.

**=> What would you recommend to have a clear interface for the component without breaking the update workflow?**

**Some ideas:**

**a)** List all used properties at the start of `render` (and `componentDidUpdate`)

```
render(){
    const text = this.props.text;
    return <div>{text}</div>;
}
```

**b)** Create a getter for each property and put them directly under the constructor, for example

```
get _text(){
    return this.props.text;
}
```

**c)** (Only for shorter access.) Try to avoid class components. With function components there is direct access with `props.text` instead of `this.props.text`. Or, as a workaround, inherit from a custom component class that passes props argument to render:

```
render_props(props){   
    ...   
}
```

(Why doesn't react pass this.props as an argument to render by default?)

**d)** Document the supported properties in a doc string

---

**=> If you know a better option / some standard / best practice, please let me know.**

**Also tried but failed:**

I tried to use `state` in the child component, with the hope that it would be automatically updated on updates of the parent state:

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Foo extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      text: props.text
    }
  }

  render(){
    return <div>{this.state.text}</div>;
  }
}
```

However, this also breaks the update workflow. Using `this.state` only seems to make sense in the parent component.

Related:

[Can I update a component's props in React.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24939623/can-i-update-a-components-props-in-react-js)

https://github.com/vasanthk/react-bits/blob/master/anti-patterns/01.props-in-initial-state.md

Related topic:

How to interact with third party libraries using function components?

https://reactjs.org/docs/integrating-with-other-libraries.html

[How do I use/include third party libraries in react?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45658200/how-do-i-use-include-third-party-libraries-in-react)

[Integrating React with Other Libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51939138/integrating-react-with-other-libraries)

Comment: If you want to add type safety, you could use [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/), [flow](https://flow.org/), ... .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use function components for React >= 16.8, also see recommendation at
  https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_class.asp
- Use `useState` hooks instead of `setState`. This is the modern way to write React, and gives you a simpler way to access state (`foo.text`, `foo.setText`). https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html
- Typescript would help with docs (`type props = { text: string }`), but I also would like the answer for **d)** (your question is several questions I think).
- Use `props.text` directly, instead of using extra shortcut variable `const text = props.text` suggested by option **a)**. This way, you don't have a list of all available properties on top of the component function. However, using a consistent `props.` prefix makes it easier to spot the injected variables in the react code. If there is a huge number of properties and its hard to identify them, try to improve modularization.

JavaScript example code:

Child component `Foo`:

```
import React from 'react';

export default function Foo(props){ 
    return <div>{props.text}</div>;
  }
}
```

Parent component:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Froo from './foo';

export default function Parent(){
  const [parentText, setParentText] = useState('Hello world');
  return <Foo text={parentText}/>;
}
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you suggest to apply *useState* inside the child component? How is that state updated from the parent component?

Comment: Class components are passé

Comment: You added part of the solution after you posted the question. Use function components.

Comment: If you're passing the state of a parent to a child via props, the child will update when the parent's state changes. Don't create a new copy of it in a field in the child, just use the prop. Typescript would give `type props = { text: string }`, making it easier to use from the parent.

Comment: Thank you for all the suggestions. I included code in the answer (did not use TypeScript, yet). Please improve example if required.

Comment: If class components are passé... Follow up question: What is the function based approach for interacting with other libraries? (I'm currently stuck on how to apply a chart library on a placeholder div created by react and update the chart data via props.) Related: a) https://reactjs.org/docs/integrating-with-other-libraries.html  b) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51939138/integrating-react-with-other-libraries

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74692822/how-to-use-third-party-libraries-with-react-functional-components